# Reference a secret's value when the key contains a (.) dot?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

My secret file looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  "user.name":  "user"
  "user.password":  "password"
```

And I am trying to get a value with the next code:

```
{{- $secret := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "secret" -}}
  {{- if $secret -}}
       {{- print $secret.data.user.password}}
```

The problem is "user.password"  key contains a dot and I haven't found how to fix it.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `index` function to access map values with dots in them like:

```
{{- print (index $secret.data "user.password")}}
```

Comment: Thank you. but how can I print the value? The next doesn't work
{{- $userPassword := index $secret.data "user.Password" }}
{{- print $userPassword }}

Comment: You don't have to use the `print` function if you are using just one variable, you should be able to just do `{{ index $secret.data "user.password" }}`. Have you checked that `$secret.data` does indeed contain a map with the data you expect?

Comment: A map with the data exists, but the problem is I am also trying to create template with this value 

{{- define "@@chartName@@.user.password" -}}
{{- $secret := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "secret" -}}
  {{- if $secret -}}
       {{- index $secret.data "user.password" }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

And now with such template my pod isn't running

Comment: Usually when people use secrets they mount then directly into the pods or make them available as env vars in the pods. By going this approach, helm will put your secret in the yaml file you are generating. This kinda defeats the purpose of secrets, is there any reason you are going with this approach? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: Yes. I have a task to create such template and reuse it